# How to view the current heap size that an application is using?

Tags: java, netbeans, heap-memory

I think I increased my heap size to 1 GB in NetBeans since I changed the config to look like this:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Xmx1g ......
```

After I restarted NetBeans, can I be sure that my app is given 1 GB now?

Is there a way to verify this?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Use this code:

```
// Get current size of heap in bytes.
long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();

// Get maximum size of heap in bytes. The heap cannot grow beyond this size.
// Any attempt will result in an OutOfMemoryException.
long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

// Get amount of free memory within the heap in bytes. This size will 
// increase after garbage collection and decrease as new objects are created.
long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

It was useful to me to know it.

Comment: You will need to recompile your app (NetBeans) if you use this strategy.

Comment: As per doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory(). Methods mentioned above returns memory in JVM not necessarily Heap Memory

Comment: Note that not all of the heap size you specify with `-J-Xmx 1g` is necessarily available for the objects of your application. The VM, especially the garbage collector, might use some of that memory. [Here's](https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/less-memory-than-xmx) a bit more on the topic.

Answer (score 24):

```
public class CheckHeapSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory(); 

        // Get maximum size of heap in bytes. The heap cannot grow beyond this size.// Any attempt will result in an OutOfMemoryException.
        long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

         // Get amount of free memory within the heap in bytes. This size will increase // after garbage collection and decrease as new objects are created.
        long heapFreeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(); 
        
        System.out.println("heap size: " + formatSize(heapSize));
        System.out.println("heap max size: " + formatSize(heapMaxSize));
        System.out.println("heap free size: " + formatSize(heapFreeSize));
        
    }
    public static String formatSize(long v) {
        if (v < 1024) return v + " B";
        int z = (63 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(v)) / 10;
        return String.format("%.1f %sB", (double)v / (1L << (z*10)), " KMGTPE".charAt(z));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this code to get HeapSize of memory in human readable format

Comment: 1 kilobyte (1 KB) = 1000 bytes. 1 kibibyte (1 KiB) = 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 17):

You can do it by MXBeans

```
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MemoryMXBean memBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean() ;
        MemoryUsage heapMemoryUsage = memBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();

        System.out.println(heapMemoryUsage.getMax()); // max memory allowed for jvm -Xmx flag (-1 if isn't specified)
        System.out.println(heapMemoryUsage.getCommitted()); // given memory to JVM by OS ( may fail to reach getMax, if there isn't more memory)
        System.out.println(heapMemoryUsage.getUsed()); // used now by your heap
        System.out.println(heapMemoryUsage.getInit()); // -Xms flag

        // |------------------ max ------------------------| allowed to be occupied by you from OS (less than xmX due to empty survival space)
        // |------------------ committed -------|          | now taken from OS
        // |------------------ used --|                    | used by your heap

    }
}
```

But remember it is equivalent to `Runtime.getRuntime()` (took depicted schema from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509942/getting-memory-statistics-in-java-runtime-vs-memorymxbean))

```
memoryMxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()      <=> runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()
memoryMxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getCommitted() <=> runtime.totalMemory()
memoryMxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax()       <=> runtime.maxMemory()
```

from [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html)

> **init** - represents the initial amount of memory (in bytes) that the
>   Java virtual machine requests from the operating system for memory
>   management during startup. The Java virtual machine may request
>   additional memory from the operating system and may also release
>   memory to the system over time. The value of init may be undefined.
>
> **used** - represents the amount of memory currently used (in bytes).
>
> **committed** - represents the amount of memory (in bytes) that is
>   guaranteed to be available for use by the Java virtual machine. The
>   amount of committed memory may change over time (increase or
>   decrease). The Java virtual machine may release memory to the system
>   and **committed** could be less than **init**. **committed** will always be
>   greater than or equal to **used**.
>
> **max** - represents the maximum amount of memory (in bytes) that can be
>   used for memory management. Its value may be undefined. The maximum
>   amount of memory may change over time if defined. The amount of used
>   and committed memory will always be less than or equal to max if max
>   is defined. A memory allocation may fail if it attempts to increase
>   the used memory such that **used** > **committed** even if **used** <= **max** would
>   still be true (for example, when the system is low on virtual memory).

```
    +----------------------------------------------+
    +////////////////           |                  +
    +////////////////           |                  +
    +----------------------------------------------+

    |--------|
       init
    |---------------|
           used
    |---------------------------|
              committed
    |----------------------------------------------|
                        max
```

As additional note, maxMemory is less than -Xmx because there is necessity at least in one empty survival space, which can't be used for heap allocation.

also it is worth to to take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210134/how-to-understand-java-lang-management-memorymxbean-and-xms) and especially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438)

Answer (score 9):

You can use jconsole (standard with most JDKs) to check heap sizes of any java process.

Comment: This includes real-time charts of memory usage, threads and classes. very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Personal favourite for when jvisualvm is overkill or you need cli-only: [jvmtop](https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop)

```
JvmTop 0.8.0 alpha   amd64  8 cpus, Linux 2.6.32-27, load avg 0.12
https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop

PID MAIN-CLASS      HPCUR HPMAX NHCUR NHMAX    CPU     GC    VM USERNAME   #T DL
3370 rapperSimpleApp  165m  455m  109m  176m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        21
11272 ver.resin.Resin [ERROR: Could not attach to VM]
27338 WatchdogManager   11m   28m   23m  130m  0.00%  0.00% S6U37 web        31
19187 m.jvmtop.JvmTop   20m 3544m   13m  130m  0.93%  0.47% S6U37 web        20
16733 artup.Bootstrap  159m  455m  166m  304m  0.12%  0.00% S6U37 web        46
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach with jvisualvm from Sun Java 6 JDK.  Startup flags are listed.

Comment: the binary is named jvisualvm(.exe).  No idea why.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use the tool : Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool  http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ .

It is very useful.