# Getting Memory Statistics in Java: Runtime vs. MemoryMXBean

Tags: java, memory-profiling

I am creating a scheduled executor to read the memory usage of the JVM. I have come across two ways to get memory statistics in a running JVM - Runtime & MemoryMXBean, with the following correspondence between their methods:

```
memoryMxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed()      <=> runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()
memoryMxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getCommitted() <=> runtime.totalMemory()
memoryMxBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax()       <=> runtime.maxMemory()
```

With the exception of the additional non-heap memory usage information provided by MemoryMXBean, are there any reasons why I should prefer it over Runtime, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 7):

There are none. JMX bean can be accessed externally and is meant for management tools like 
hyperic ( or even nagios ) -  It would delegate to  Runtime anyway.

Comment: Yes. Both ways return exactly the same value for the used memory.