# How to upload a file of 750MB in JAVA, using jersey-client V2.13 (from a client to a server)?

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey, jersey-client

Just before starting to explain you my problem, I would like to share with you the libraries' versions that I use and the server:

```
javax.ws.rs-api: 2.0.1
jersey-container-servlet: 2.13
jersey-media-multipart: 2.13
jackson: 2.4.3  

I also use Apache Tomcat Server version 7.0.55.
```

So I coded that below:

```
    /**
     * On the client side.
     */
public void uploadAFile() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
            .build();

    WebTarget target = null;
    try {
        target = client
                .target("https://blo-bla.rhcloud.com/rest")
                .path("v1").path("upload");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        LOG_TO_CONSOLE.fatal(e, e);
        LOG_TO_FILE.fatal(e, e);
    }

    Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    builder.header("Authorization",
    getValidBasicAuthenticationStrEncrypted());

    FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
    form.field("anotherParam", "Bozo");

    String fileName = "/Users/drizzy/Documents/Divx/CaseDepartFolder/sample.avi";

    File file = new File(fileName);
    form.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));

    Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(form,
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE));

    LOG_TO_CONSOLE.debug(response.getStatus());
    LOG_TO_CONSOLE.debug(response.readEntity(String.class));
}


   /**
     * On the server side.
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                             @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition,
                             @FormDataParam("anotherParam") String str) 
                             throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("str: " + str);
        final String basePath = "/Users/drizzy/eclipse-workspace/tomcat7jbossews"
                                + "/src/main/resources/uploads/";

        final String fileName = fileDisposition.getFileName();
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("***** fileName ")
                                              .append(fileName)
                                              .toString());

        final String filePath = new StringBuilder().append(basePath)
                                                   .append(fileName)
                                                   .toString();
        System.out.println(filePath);

        try (OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath)) {
            int read = 0;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        }

        return "File Upload Successfully !!";
    }
```

Which generates these exceptions at the client side:

```
Java Heap space error
```

and

```
Java binding Exception: Already connected
```

So my question is to know if somebody could please provide me an example of code with a client using jersey-client V2.13 which uploads a big file from the client to the server? Or even could telling me what is wrong in my code above?

Note: I only want to use jersey-client version V2.13 for handling that problem, so please do not provide me solutions using third party libraries or which do not use jersey-client version V2.13.

Comment: What do you understand under "a big file"? Most servers Tomcat including have limits (in configuration) how big a file can be when uploaded.

Comment: If the server has a limit and you don't want to change it, you're stuck. How to change it depends on the framework, not on the container: there isn't a generic technique.

Comment: Wrong about what exactly? I haven't said anything wrong here.

Comment: If you're going to tell people that they're wrong you need to state why. I haven't said anything wrong here. My comment starts with an 'if', and I haven't denied or precluded the existence of any bug. You need to read more carefully, and be prepared to back up your statements. You introduced he topic, so it can't be irrelevant.

Comment: My solution is the same as in all the previous threads I have contributed to on this topic, including one yesterday which may have been yours, now apparently deleted. Find a way to enable chunked transfer mode. That's also what it says in the bug report. If you no longer think I'm wrong you should delete the comment that says so.

Comment: My posting here was not an answer but a comment. You still haven't stated what was wrong with it and you haven't retracted either. And yes I do mind being told I'm wrong when I'm not. And SO makes specific provision for posting comments as opposed to answers: you have no business telling anybody not to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution to my problem:

**1 - For fixing the "Already connected" Exception.**

Java 7 introduced SNI support which is enabled by default. I have found out that certain misconfigured servers send an "Unrecognized Name" warning in the SSL handshake which is ignored by most clients... except for Java. As @Bob Kerns mentioned, the Oracle engineers refuse to "fix" this bug/feature.

As workaround, they suggest to set the jsse.enableSNIExtension property. To allow your programs to work without re-compiling, run your app as:

```
"-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"
```

Source of this information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0).

The property can also be set in the Java code, but it must be set before any SSL actions. Once the SSL library has loaded, you can change the property, but it won't have any effect on the SNI status. To disable SNI on runtime (with the aforementioned limitations), use:

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
```

**2 - For fixing the chunkedTransferMode's activation and java heap space error.**

Java heap space error: I had to increase the jvm memory used by the client:

For doing that In eclipse, go to Run > Run Configurations ... > Select the client class > Arguments > VM arguments:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx2500m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

Sources that I used myself for fixing that problem: [source 1](http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-tomcat-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/), [source 2](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/setting-tomcat-heap-size-jvm-heap-eclipse/), [source 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015463/how-to-view-the-current-heap-size-that-an-applicatin-is-using).

Regarding the fact of enabling the chunkedTransferMode, I did not need to do that, because I found in the documentation of jersey-client that the chunkedTransferMode was enabled by default in jersey-client V2.13.

In the end we pass these parameters to the JVM at the client side:

```
"-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false" "your classes ..." -Xms1024m -Xmx2500m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that the problem is a really large file (350Mb) and you are hitting various limits. Therefore I would suggest to address the problem in a different way.

Possible solutions:

1. Split the file on the client and upload it via "smaller" parts to the server where it is assembled back in original order.
2. Stream a file to the server: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html

I would prefer the 2. solution as it is probably the easiest to implement.
Hope this helps.