# How to get the current heap size that an android application is using?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I found that it can be easily done using java from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015524) but couldn't find yet how to do it if my applicating is written using C#.NET and xamarin libraries. How to get those same datas (current heap size, maximum heap size) using this framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that those values are not especially useful in Android app development. In particular, the amount of reported free heap space does not indicate how much you can allocate in a single request, as Android's heap suffers from fragmentation much of the time.

Comment: I see, I need those datas anyway since it was requested for me.. but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
long memory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
```

It retrieves the number of bytes currently thought to be allocated.

There is also another option:

```
Process currentProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long memoryUsed = currentProc.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

You determine memory usage by reading the `PrivateMemorySize64` property. You need `using System.Diagnostics;` reference to support this action.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
//get max heap available to app
var activityManager = (ActivityManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
int maxHeap = activityManager.MemoryClass*1024; //KB

//get current heap used by app
Runtime runtime = Runtime.GetRuntime();
int usedHeap = (int)((runtime.TotalMemory() - runtime.FreeMemory()) / 1024.0f); //KB

//get amount of free heap remaining for app
int availableHeap = maxHeap - usedHeap;
```