# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Intellij cannot work even if i change memory space

Tags: spring, kotlin, intellij-idea

[image]

I was just ruined by this error for the whole week. I really don't know what happened, I got this error after compiling the source, I yet write custom code there, the source is fresh from the repo. I asked my friend to run the source and it worked on his laptop.

What I was tried to fix this problem :

1. File -> Invalidate Cache
2. Help -> Change Memory Setting (all size was tried) (current size: 2048)
3. Intellij -> Preference -> Compiler -> Shared Build Process Heap Size (all size was tried) (current size: 6048)

And I am still stuck at that error.

Lately I run this command `./gradlew build --stacktrace --info` to see the log, and i had no idea what was that. this is the full result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to add gradle.properties file in the project root directory (next to build.gradle) and add the following there: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Xmx4g`

Comment: Did the execution generate a heap dump? If so, you might want to analyze it with a tool like Eclipse Memory Analyzer.

Comment: Did you verify your used heap size?

Comment: Changing `Intellij -> Preference -> Compiler -> Shared Build Process Heap Size` in case of same error on Scala with SBT helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your suggestions guys. I've done it all and got the same result.

finally, I can escape from this bug by running this command `./gradlew build` in the terminal and close my Intellij. I don't know what really happened, but now it all working perfectly.

I want to ask u guys, I am new in mac, are partitioning disk in mac book take an effect on its performance?

Comment: Hello Arma, that is a not perfect solution but it works right. 
I would let you know that you can just edit your question or comment on it to make it more clear to reader the soulion you've taken.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign more heap

- for your ide --> help | change memory settings
- for your current programm --> Run | Edit Configurations... see screenshot

[image]

- for all programs -->

  - Set Environment Variable: SET _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m
    or
  - File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler and set user User-local build process VM options with like 2048

[image]

Verify heap size with [How to view the current heap size that an application is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015463/how-to-view-the-current-heap-size-that-an-application-is-using)